# Deserializing buffer Protocol Buffer

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm trying to deserialize buffer from socket.
It is defined as C struct.

One member of struct is uint8[5].
I stuck how to express that with .proto file.

Original C struct of sender is at below.

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t body_length;
    uint8_t body_version; 
    uint8_t reserved[5];
}
```

My struct.proto trial is at below.

```
syntax = "proto3";
message message_t {
        uint32 body_version = 1;
        uint8 body_version = 2;  //uint8_t body_version;
        bytes reserved = 3;  //uint8 reservered[5];
}
```

I don't know how to express uint8 and 5 byte sized array.
There's no uint8 and fixed size bytes at proto3 spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

protobuf indeed doesn't have fixed size arrays, and the fixed size integers don't include 5 bytes. So; your best option is probably `bytes`, and just make it *always contain* exactly 5 bytes.

Note: protobuf is not intended as a mechanism for parsing arbitrary protocols / payloads such as socket frames or raw C-style dumps. It is **only** intended for use with protobuf itself.